# Instance Selection from a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, data-mining

I am a begineer and just trying to learn more about this technique. I am trying to do Instance Selection from a dataset containing 15000 instances. I want to select 5000 instances out of those 15000 using instance selection algorithm and those 5000 instances will act as the training data and used for classification. I am planning on using Random Mutation Hill Climbing implemented in Python for that. But I am not sure if I would really be able to achieve the target with it. Can anyone please suggest me some other options or share more details about it?